# Why does SonarQube consider int[][][] not serializable

Tags: java, sonarqube, serializable

In my code I have the following line:

```
private int[][][] shapes;
```

In the wild it lives inside an enum:

```
public enum TetrisGamePiece {
    private int id;
    private int pieceColour;
    private int[][][] shapes; // <-- This line is not accepted

    private TetrisGamePiece(int id, int colour, int[][] shape1, int[][] shape2, int[][] shape3, int[][] shape4) {
        this.id = id;
        this.pieceColour = colour;
        this.shapes = new int[][][]{shape1, shape2, shape3, shape4};
    }
    // ... the rest of the enum ... 
    // i've left out instantiation of objects to save space.
```

and I get the following mention from sonarqube:

> Make "shapes" transient or serializable.  Fields in a Serializable
>   class must themselves be either Serializable or transient even if the
>   class is never explicitly serialized or deserialized. That's because
>   under load, most J2EE application frameworks flush objects to disk,
>   and an allegedly Serializable object with non-transient,
>   non-serializable data members could cause program crashes, and open
>   the door to attackers.

As far as I was aware, int[] (and int[][] etc) are serializable. Is this a bug in sonarqube or am I misunderstanding the serializability of arrays of basic types?

edit: added the enum this lives in, just in case the enum type is relevant

Comment: sounds like a bug in sonarqube.

Comment: @jtahlborn thanks :) I was doubting my sanity for a bit

Comment: Indeed, all primitives and their wrappers are serializeable in java and so are their arrays..

Comment: heh, been there.  when it seems too obvious, you sometimes wonder if you're missing something!

Comment: Is it worth leaving this question up for others or is there no value to it?

Comment: Please ask in sonarqube community (http://www.sonarqube.org/resources/join-our-community/)  and leave the link here:

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Ticket created in the Java plugin: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-918

Comment: thanks @SimonBrandhof, it is ofcourse no inconvenience. I've added more details above in case it helps. If there's anything else just let me know, I love using sonar so whatever I can do to help :D

Comment: @SimonBrandhof-SonarSource This rule (squid:S1948)  also complains for enums. In this article it is demonstrated that enums behave like primitives and therefore no need to explicitly state that it's Serializable: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072870/java-enums-are-inherently-serializable.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by @Simon Brandhof this is indeed a bug in the selected rule.

The issue is due to the fact that primitive are not considered as serializable by the check.
Ticket https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-918 will fix this issue. 
Thanks for reporting.